# Python: How to create a list for every line in my file?

Tags: python, list, file, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a file with sites that I am scraping and I would like to create for each site a special list that will contain a pids that I am adding later to it. For example.

site.com has pids 32, 41, 34

site1.com has pids 58, 746, 743, 754

```py
sites = read_from_txt("sites.txt")
for site in sites:
    pids = [] # List that I am adding all pids
    r = requests.get(site, headers=headers)
    page = soup(r.content, "html.parser")
    if page.find('ul', {'id':'products'}) != None:
        ul = page.find('ul', {'id':'products'})
        for product in ul.find_all('li'):
            pid = product.find('input', {'name': 'productId'}).attrs['value']
            pids.append(pid)      
    else:
        pass
```

Reading from sites file is basic.

Comment: you are initializing pids to an empty list at each iteration. it that what you want?

Comment: yes, every line from file need to have it's own empty list

Comment: FYI: There's no need for `else: pass`.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the list before you clear it for the next site. Maybe you should collect these in another list?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you like to do but I think you can store the information in a "global" `list` as simple list:

```
data.append(pids)
```

or as `dict`:

```
data.append({
    'site':site,
    'pids':pids
)
```

###### Example

```
sites = read_from_txt("sites.txt")

data = []

for site in sites:
    pids = [] # List that I am adding all pids
    r = requests.get(site, headers=headers)
    page = soup(r.content, "html.parser")
    if page.find('ul', {'id':'products'}) != None:
        ul = page.find('ul', {'id':'products'})
        for product in ul.find_all('li'):
            pid = product.find('input', {'name': 'productId'}).attrs['value']
            pids.append(pid)      

    data.append(pids)

print(data)
```

Comment: Will it create for each site different pid list ?

Comment: Why not give it a try?